# Will this system undergo simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

I was recently studying Simple Harmonic Motion, In which I came across a problem.

[image]

It deals with small angular oscillation (a light shaking of Sphere), I extended this problem and asked my teacher that  How would be the motion of a sphere when it is translated to a large distance? What type of oscillations (SHM) would be?  He said the system won't undergo oscillation(SHM) as acceleration is not related to displacement but how that's possible. Won't it be a combination of angular & linear SHM?

Comment: What analysis have you done to support your contention?

Comment: @BillN I haven't done any analysis. It just my Intuition(or like a thought experiment ) about the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

the answer to your question is yes. you get harmonic motion

lets look at the equation of motion:

the kinetic energy is :

$$T=\frac 12 M\,\dot x^2+\frac 12 I_s\,\dot\varphi^2$$
with $~\dot\varphi=\frac{\dot x}{R}~,I_s=\frac 25 M\,R^2$

the spring force has two  components
$$\vec F_c=\begin{bmatrix}
   F_x\\
   F_y \\
    0\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

you obtain due to this force a torque about the z axis which is:

$$\tau_\varphi=d\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\varphi)\\
   \sin(\varphi) \\
   0
 \end{bmatrix}\times \vec F_c=d\cos \left( {\frac {x}{R}} \right) {\it F_y}-d\sin \left( {\frac {x}{R
}} \right) {\it F_x}
$$

the EOM

$$\ddot{x}+\frac 57\,\frac{1}{M\,R}\left[{\it F_x}\, \left( d\sin \left( {\frac {x}{R}} \right) -R \right)
-\,d\cos \left( {\frac {x}{R}} \right) {
\it F_y}\right]=0\tag 1$$

spring force:
$$\vec F_c=c\,(\parallel \vec e_c\parallel-l_0)\,\frac {\vec e_c}{\parallel\vec e_c\parallel}=\begin{bmatrix}
   F_x\\
   F_y \\
0
 \end{bmatrix}\tag 2$$
where:
$$\vec e_c=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x+d\cos \left( {\frac {x}{R}} \right) 
\\ d\sin \left( {\frac {x}{R}} \right) -a
\\ 0\end {array} \right] 
$$
and
$$l_0=\parallel\vec e_c\parallel\bigg|_{x=0}=\sqrt{d^2+a^2}$$

if you now substitute the spring force components Eq. (2) into the equation of motion (Eq. (1)) and linearize you obtain

$$\ddot{x}+\underbrace{\frac 57\,{\frac {c\,{d}^{2} \left( R-a\right) ^{2}}{M \left( {d}
^{2}+{a}^{2} \right) {R}^{2}}}}_{\omega^2}\,x
=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The elongation in spring would not change linearly with the distance moved by the sphere. So force on it would not be linearly dependent with the displacement. But in SHM, $F\propto x$

Comment: How the elongation in spring isn't linear?

Comment: It isn't linear when the sphere is rolling. It is easy to see that the point where spring is attached to sphere doesn't move away from the Wall with the same speed as the sphere's center

Answer (score 0):

As the sphere *rolls* forward, you can see the point of contact of the sphere and the spring would no longer just have a horizontal velocity but also a component of *tangential* velocity would dive in for a downward component.

[image: sphere and spring]

Once the angle by which sphere has rotated (about its geometrical or mass centre) is no longer negligible, neither can be this vertical component of $\omega d$.

[image: sphere rotated by angle]

This downward component will pull the point of contact and the spring connected to it. And the fun thing is, this $\omega$ is about the center of mass of the sphere and not the one you obtained from the equation of SHM. And this $\omega$ is itself a varying quantity over the variable of time. This varying quantity multiplied by another sinusoidally changing function of another variable $\theta$ which itself depends upon $\omega$ and/or time (depends completely on the way you write the expressions). Do you think they will combine to give an angular shm component?
(Kindly do notice, the velocity of centre of mass is also a variable.)

The calculations will go really messy. But I can certainly assure you of one thing, there would exists a different kind of complex periodic motion (only if the friction is sufficient enough).